# SharePoint changing relative links in aspx files in Document Library randomly

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have a very weird anomoly that stopped for a couple months but somehow started up again.

In my SharePoint online, within a Document Library on a site, I have folders with `index.aspx` files.  As scripting is enabled by the site admin, these `index.aspx` files directly render in the browser and work great for custom landing pages/dashboards etc.

Within the `index.aspx` I have relative links (links to JS, assets, etc) that are in the same folder.  However, very occassionaly, these relative links will somehow change to absolute out of nowhere, and be wrong, breaking my custom site.

For instance, if my Sharepoint domain is *foo.sharepoint.com* and I have a script tag in `index.aspx` such as `<script src="flutter.js" defer></script>`, this will magically change to `<script src="https://foo.sharepoint.com./flutter.js" defer></script>`  So it's not even a correct absolute link, as it doesn't include the Site, document library, and so forth in the absolute link.  *Note: The weird `./` in the link is because I have `<base href="./">` as well.*

I have no idea why this randomly happens, and it's also not caught by versioning nor does the timestamp change.  If I look at version history there is no new entry.  I thought maybe it had something to do with people folder sharing (someone shares the folder with a peer causing the links to change), but I can't replicate.  But I did notice a similar behavior if perform "Copy To"  on the index.aspx and make a copy, in that copy all the links have changed to the wrong absolute-paths in the same fashion as above.  So this leads me to think maybe this a weird Sharepoint backup action causing it?  Help is appreciated!